# Can I declare the hibernate.dialect value from a file outside my web application?

Tags: hibernate

My webapp may use SQL or ORACLE as DBMS.

Is there a way to declare the `hibernate.dialect` anywhere outside the war, so I can have the same WAR file being deployed in a SQL or ORACLE environment?

Currently this property is defined in `persistence.xml`.

note: The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) states that this is an optional property, but also tell us to always set its value to the correct dialect. I would rather follow the doc's advice and set the proper value...

Comment: ??? What docs are you reading? I've always found that actually setting the dialect manually has caused me issues because I selected the wrong one (esp with MySQL and Oracle databases because each one has 5 different dialects apiece)

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects